# object declaration in setUp method is not working

Tags: java, junit

I declared an object for a class in setup method in its test class. when i try to access it from its Test method, the method could not access it.

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
   Medicine med= new Medicine("Medicine1", 110011, 100, 60);
}

@Test
public void testSetName()
{
    med.setName("ChangeMedicine");
    assertEquals("ChangeMedicine",med.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the scope of `Medicine` to class level and it should work -

```
public class ClassInTest {

    private Medicine med;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        med= new Medicine("Medicine1", 110011, 100, 60);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        med.setName("ChangeMedicine");
        assertEquals("ChangeMedicine",med.getName());
    }
}
```